# Group by on nested laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have started working on some data analyising, and the data is really messy, so i have to convert timestamps to readable date and time and such..

I have tried standard group by but it was not successful because the array is nested and i have no idea how to approach.

```
 Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
   (
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Entity 1
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 08.07.2019
                                [time] => 00:00
                                [counter] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 08.07.2019
                                [time] => 01:00
                                [counter] => 3
                            )

                        [167] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 14.07.2019
                                [time] => 23:00
                                [counter] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Entity 2
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 08.07.2019
                                [time] => 00:00
                                [counter] => 0
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 08.07.2019
                                [time] => 01:00
                                [counter] => 4
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 08.07.2019
                                [time] => 02:00
                                [counter] => 12
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 09.07.2019
                                [time] => 03:00
                                [counter] => 0
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 10.07.2019
                                [time] => 04:00
                                [counter] => 4
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 11.07.2019
                                [time] => 05:00
                                [counter] => 17
                            )

                    )

            )
```

So what would be the correct way to group this by date so i could get one array for one date for example

date 08.07:
    time: 02:00
    counter: 12

```
timer: 04:00
counter: 1
```

date 14.07:
    time: 05:00
    counter: 1

```
time: 08:00
counter: 3

time: 01:00
counter: 6
```

Sorry for dump example of an array

I have tried something like:

```
$collection = collect($values);
$groupedBy = $collection->groupBy('date);
```

But that just doesn't work since it's a nested array.

Answer (score 1):

Before grouping you could reduce the collection in order to have only the items' values. After that you can simply use group by date and time:

```
$grouped = $collection
    ->reduce(function(Collection $carry, $item) {
        return $carry->merge($item['values']);
    }, new Collection())
    ->groupBy(function($item) {
        return sprintf('%s %s', $item['date'], $item['time']);
    });
```

where `Collection` is the imported `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

Comment: It kinda does the job but on the other way, I'm not sure how but some of the items are doubled, for example the api will send me back data
for every hour in a day, that is like 24 items in an array, now somehow i get like 100+